# How to efficiently use inverse and determinant in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-inverse, determinants

In Eigen there are [recommendations](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) that warn against the explicit calculation of determinants and inverse matrices.

I'm implementing the posterior predictive for the multivariate normal with a normal-inverse-wishart prior distribution. This can be expressed as a multivariate t-distribution.

In the multivariate t-distribution you will find a term `|Sigma|^{-1/2}` as well as `(x-mu)^T Sigma^{-1} (x-mu)`.

I'm quite ignorant with respect to Eigen. I can imagine that for a positive semidefinite matrix (it is a covariance matrix) I can use the LLT solver.

There are however no `.determinant()` and `.inverse()` methods defined on the solver itself. Do I have to use the `.matrixL()` function and inverse the elements on the diagonal myself for the inverse, as well as calculate the product to get the determinant? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: You can use a cholesky decomposition to calculate the inverse of a covariance matrix. This is well-documented.

Comment: We might need to see more of the equation...my gut feeling is that if you transformed to working in a Jacobian/eigen value decomposition space, you may be able to do the whole calculation there where the errors and time complexity inherent in dense matrix inversion/determinants will simply go away.

Comment: @Bathsheba In Eigen the LLT solver is used for Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: @IdeaHat The complete equation is a bit involved. It can be found in [Conjugate Bayesian analysis of the Gaussian distribution (2007) Murphy](http://www-devel.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf). The posterior predictive is eq. 258. The multivariate t-distribution is eq. 313. My current implementation can be found at [github](https://github.com/mrquincle/aim_modules/blob/master/DirichletModule/src/DirichletModuleExt.cpp).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Cholesky factorization of `Sigma=LL^T` and want `(x-mu)^T*Sigma^{-1}*(x-mu)`, you can compute: `(llt.matrixL().solve(x-mu)).squaredNorm()` (assuming `x` and `mu` are vectors).

For the square root of the determinant, just calculate `llt.matrixL().determinant()` (calculating the determinant of a triangular matrix is just the product of its diagonal elements).